# Carousel in Vue-Bootstrap is not loading as intended

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am trying to Build a carousel using Vue Bootstrap. For some reason the Carousel images are all visible at the same time. I checked the inspect element and only one of the images are active at one time.

I have installed all the required dependencies. However, it is still not working.


 Home.vue File

```
<div class="Home">
    <b-carousel
      id="carousel-fade" fade indicators>
      <b-carousel-slide caption="First slide" img-src="coffee-roaster.jpg"></b-carousel-slide>
      <b-carousel-slide caption="Second Slide" img-src="coffee-plant.jpg"></b-carousel-slide>
      <b-carousel-slide caption="Third Slide" img-src="coffee-bean.jpg"></b-carousel-slide>
    </b-carousel>
</div>
```

main.js file

```
// Bootstrap import
import {
  BootstrapVue, IconsPlugin, CarouselPlugin, VBScrollspyPlugin, LayoutPlugin,
} from 'bootstrap-vue';
// Bootstrap Dependencies
import PortalVue from 'portal-vue';
// Vee-Validate
import { ValidationObserver, ValidationProvider, extend } from 'vee-validate';
import {
  alpha, required, email, is,
} from 'vee-validate/dist/rules';
// Vue Imports
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';

// Initialise in the app
// BootStrap
Vue.use(BootstrapVue);
Vue.use(IconsPlugin);
Vue.use(LayoutPlugin);
Vue.use(VBScrollspyPlugin);
Vue.use(CarouselPlugin);
Vue.use(PortalVue);

// Vee-Validate
Vue.component('ValidationProvider', ValidationProvider);
Vue.component('ValidationObserver', ValidationObserver);
extend('alpha', {
  ...alpha,
  message: 'Please input a valid email',
});
extend('email', {
  ...email,
  message: 'Please input a valid email',
});
extend('required', {
  ...required,
  message: 'This field is required',
});
extend('is', {
  ...is,
  message: 'Please accept the Terms and Conditions',
});

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  components: {
    ValidationProvider,
    ValidationObserver,
  },
  router,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

**The Result**
[image]

Comment: Where are you importing Bootstrap and Bootstrap-vue CSS?

Comment: @Hiws Oh thank you!!  I missed it out